# How to know I'm in the first cycle of fetchArray() loop

Tags: php

I want to print an attribute (i.e. `active`) on the first element of an array.
The ugly way is to use a variable:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <?php $firstItem = true; ?>
    <?php while ($row = $res_sections->fetchArray()) { ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link<?php if ($firstItem) echo ' active' ?>" data-toggle="pill" href="#nav<?= $row['section']?>"><?php echo "{$row["section"]}"?></a>
    </li>
    <?php $firstItem = false; ?>
    <?php } ?>      
</ul>
```

I wonder if there's something more elegant.
Is there a way to know if `$row` is the first element (or any) of the `fetchArray()` result?

### EDIT

Here where `fetchArray()` comes from:

```
$db = new SQLite3("/db.sqlite");
$sql_sections = "SELECT DISTINCT section FROM settings";
$res_sections = $db->query(SQLite3::escapeString($sql_sections));
```

Comment: There is an index to `$row` which would indicate order. Not sure what you're after here.

Comment: It's not disgusting for me to put a flag as you write initially. There are tons of ways to put that flag, but essentially is the same.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, if there's an index associated to `$row` I'm fine. I just don't realize how to get it.

Comment: What is `fetchArray()` returning you?  Is this from a certain framework?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, question updated with more details about `fetchArray()`

Comment: @Mark Looking at the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php), it seems the only way to get the row count/index is to basically do what you are doing.  I guess you can abstract that out into its own method, but you still need to just make a counter in the `while` loop.

Comment: Just to point out to OP in case your not aware, this complication can be removed by extracting the query result to an array instead of using the `fetchArray()` iterator, if that's not a requirement.